# Sending Mails in a a foreach loop in Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel, foreach

I have this requirement, where I need to send separate mails to all the users in TO and CC header from my application.

So, for example, I add abc@xyz.com in TO; asd@fgh.com in, qwe@rty.com in CC. There are three email-ids here, cumulative of TO and CC.

I need to send a separate mail to all three. So, abc@xyz.com will only see his name in the Mail header, and so on for CC recipients.

My approach was to merge all the emails in an array, and then run a foreach loop, something like this:

```
foreach($emails as $email) {
    Mail::send(..... 
    {
        $message->to($email);
    });
}
```

Is this a better way to do this? Or any other much better approach that I can follow?

Comment: If you have a lot of users it's a bad idea to do that syncronously while the request is being processed because it will most likely timeout. It would be better to [queue](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#queueing-mail) the emails sending process using `Mail::queue`. Also if you have a lot of users you might want to consider using a separate service for sending emails, to avoid any problems that might arise from trying to send a large volume in a short time.

Comment: What separate service I can use?

Comment: There are many out there and it depends if you're looking for a free service or not. For example [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/) and [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/) have free plans that allow you to send up to 12000 email/month, or you can use any of the paid plans depending on your needs. You can of course use [Mandrill](https://www.mandrill.com/) or [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) for which Laravel has out of the box integration.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!empty($users)) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        Mail::send('emails.acitvation', ['item' => $xyz, 'user' => $user],
            function ($message) use ($user) {
                $message->subject('your subject here');
                $message->to($user['email']);
            });
    }
}
```